# WWDC 2010 videos

Tags: iphone

Are these WWDC 2020 videos free or paid?
I have a valid apple ID, do i still need to pay for them? What is the link from where I can download these videos?

Comment: 2020!? You must be mistaken, that's ten years in the future!

Comment: Its 2021 and they are still free to watch :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They're free. You can find them [here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/wwdc/2010/).

Comment: Note you have to have paid the $99 developer program fee for access, not just have an Apple ID.

Comment: Paid program is not required. I just tested with another non-paid account that I have.

Answer (score 0):

This belongs on another site (programmers.se or apple.se). That said, as long as you are a *paid* developer, you can get them for free. You need to go to the apple developer site and log in. There will be links there.